# Xcode couldn't find a profile matching - Ionic Cordova

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am trying to run:

> sudo ionic cordova build --release ios

But I get this error:

> Check dependencies
>           No iOS profile matching 'myappName' 
>           found:  Xcode couldn't find a profile matching 'myappName'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto 
>           Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the General tab of the 
>           target editor.
>           Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 
>           10.3'
>
> ** ARCHIVE FAILED **

I am sure that I have a working Provisioning profile. I have tried some solutions I found online, like force code signing, but nothing worked. 
Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have your provisioning profile set to MyAppName in build.json.  Your build.json needs to follow the following guidelines:

```
{
"ios": {
    "debug": {
    "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
    "developmentTeam":"YOURTEAMID",
    "provisioningProfile": "provisioning profile name or UUID",
    "packageType": "development"
    },
    "release": {
    "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Distribution",
    "developmentTeam":"YOURTEAMID",
    "provisioningProfile": "provisioning profile name or UUID",
    "packageType": "ad-hoc"
    }
  }
}
```

You provisioning profile needs to be created and downloaded from apple.developer.com.  The profile is specific to the app you are building, and internally has been coded with the applications bundle id. e.g com.company.MyApp.  The name to use in your build.json is the literal name of the profile as downloaded from apple without the extension.  The name is also contained inside the file is your search for UUID.  The UUID is also identified inside the file.  When you double click the file it will be installed in the ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles directory, renamed to .mobileprovision

Answer (score 3):

If you build app on MS Code then running app on XCode, unplug your IPhone device usb cable before building.